# Webform contribution for multiple items?

Tags: webform-civicrm, contributions

In a webform, I want to offer a selection of prices and quantities (like a simple price set).

For example:

```
  Thing A  $10  [quantity box]
  Thing B  $20  [quantity box]
```

I've added a Contribution on the webform and ticked the box to add the contribution amount to the form. It seems like it should just be a matter of changing the widget type for the contribution amount to the right thing ... but I haven't found the right widget :-(

'Select options' lets me select 0/1 of each item, but not a user-entered quantity.

What widget type will do that?  Alternatively, any other suggestions for structuring the webform to achieve this?

[I want to use a webform for its other features that I don't get with a priceset and contribution page.]

(Drupal 7, CiviCRM 4.6.18)

Answer (score 2):

How about something like this:

1. Finite quantities for each item (if you have too many - make them select lists).
2. Calculate the Contribution Amount w/ some jQuery - [just like on CiviCRM contribution pages] - OR - if you don't have too many combinations - you can do this via Webform Conditionals - so no code required.

[image]

Comment: PS - of course CiviCRM will have no idea on what people purchased - but the monies will add up. And you've got Results in Webform to tell you how many mugs and pens to ship to people.